# Codeception Error | Class “Yii” not found

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

Hello i created a new project to learn codeception.

But when i run “codecept run” i get the Following error:

> Open contact page (ContactFormCest::openContactPage)
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
> Class ‘Yii’ not found

My bootstrap file:

```
?php
define(‘YII_ENV’, ‘test’);
defined(‘YII_DEBUG’) or define(‘YII_DEBUG’, true);
require(DIR . “/…/vendor/autoload.php”);
require(DIR . “/…/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php”);
$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/console.php');
$application = new yiiconsoleApplication( $config );
```

my codeception.yml:

```
actor: Tester
bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
 paths:
  tests: tests
  log: tests/_output
  data: tests/_data
  helpers: tests/_support
settings:
 memory_limit: 1024M
 colors: true
modules:
 config:
     Yii2:
         configFile: 'config/test.php'
```

Comment: How did you create the project, are you using Yii's basic template? Did you run `codecept build` before `codecept run`?

Comment: Yeah i used the Yii basic template and builded before.